# javascript: find first truthy returned value from array of functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

let's say I have an array of validation function that returns an error message or null, I want to iterate over the array and find the returned value of the first function that didn't return null, that do you think is the best way to implement it?

Comment: This question will probably lead to opinionated answers, which is off topic.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I thought it will be the best place to ask it, do you think that I need to delete it?

Comment: Does your current solution have an issue? Or are you looking for approval or support for your approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go through the various functions with `Array.prototype.findIndex()` as this will end after the first truthy return value:

```js
// test for:   number          string                 array
const funarr=[ (a=>!isNaN(a)), a=>typeof a=="string", (a=>Array.isArray(a)) ];

["word",123,[1,2,3]].forEach(v=>console.log(v, funarr.findIndex(f=>f(v))))
```

Or, if you want to have the first "error" returned you can do this:

```js
const funarr=[ 
  a=>!isNaN(a)&&"number", 
  a=>typeof a=="string" && "string",
  a=>Array.isArray(a) && "array" ];

console.log(
 ["word",123,[1,2,3]].map((c,i)=>(funarr.some(f=>i=f(c)), i), "")
)

// used in a single call, this becomes:
let err=""
funarr.some(f=>err=f("another example"));
console.log(err);
```

Comment: this second option is very nice. might use it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```js
const falsy = (a) => !a;
const truthy = (a) => a;

const  arr = [falsy, falsy, truthy, falsy, truthy];

const getError() = (arr, args) => {
  const errorFunc = arr.find(func => func(args));
  return errorFunc && errorFunc(args)
}

const error = getError(arr, 'a');
console.log(error)
```